# ImageView array not keeping aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-imageview

I have a small problem that I think it is easily fixable by someone more experienced. In an ImageView I set all attributes in xml as I wanted and it was displaying my image perfectly fine. Then I decided to make an imageView array and to change the image each time something happened in my app. This is the xml I had before that was displaying perfectly fine:

```
`<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/questions_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_q1"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/view_groups_good"
            android:layout_below="@id/score_no"/>`
```

After the creation of the array I have removed from the xml the android :src attribute and created this method that I call each time I want to change the image.

This is what I have before onCreate

```
int [] imageAllQ = {R.drawable.view1, R.drawable.view2, R.drawable.view3, R.drawable.view4, R.drawable.view5, R.drawable.view6, R.drawable.view7, R.drawable.view8, R.drawable.view9, R.drawable.view10};
int imgCount = 0;
ImageView questionsViews;
```

And this is the method:

```
public void changeImgQA (){
    questionsViews = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.questions_image_view);
    questionsViews.setBackgroundResource(imageAllQ[imgCount]);
    imgCount = imgCount + 1;
}
```

Everything works exactly as I want, but now the image view does not take into account the xml attributes and the image displayed is distorted, I mean it is match parent on width but on height it is completely distorted, being too small compared to what I want.

Any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use**

```
questionsViews.setImageResource(imageAllQ[imgCount]);
```

Instead of

```
questionsViews.setBackgroundResource(imageAllQ[imgCount]);
```

**Cause**

[setImageResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) is a public method of `ImageView` and is responsible to set the source of the `ImageView` to the given resource.

> Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

[setBackgroundResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)) is a public method of `View` and is responsible to set the background of the `View` to the given resource.

> Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background.

**BTW**

You should initialize your `ImageView` once inside `onCreate` and then re-use it instead of calling `findViewById` every time you change the image.

Comment: You are completely right, I just solved the issue when you gave me the answer. Do you know why is that happening with setBackgroundResource? Just for my general knowledge

Answer (score 1):

use `scaleType = centerCrop` , this should preserve the aspect ratio along `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

setBackGroundResource , Set the background to a given resource.However setImageBackground, Sets a drawable as the content of this ImageView.

that is why there is that distortion.

Comment: Because setImageResource() automatically scale your image.

Comment: also modify your code, so there only a single instance-of imageview at any given time, currently your code will always re find it.

Comment: Thank you Caspain, I already modified that once @Nika answered. Thank you for the other explanation also.